# Golang code too slow for Hackerrank

Tags: algorithm, performance, go

I've been trying to solve this Hackerrank challenge: [Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-grid-search)

This is what you have to do:

You have one large matrix:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1
```

and one small matrix:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
```

You have to find out if the small matrix is present in the large matrix.

There are up to 5 testcases and each matrix can be of max 1000x1000 size and I need to solve this in under 4 seconds.

My code timeouts for the largest possible input, I thought that maybe how I'm scanning the matrix is too slow.

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var t, rL, cL, rS, cS, temp int
    var s string
    var sl []string
    var mxL, mxS [][]int
    var found bool
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &t)
    for ; t > 0; t-- {
        // Start scanning input
        // Scanning large matrix
        fmt.Scanf("%d%d", &rL, &cL)
        mxL = make([][]int, rL)
        for i := range mxL {
            mxL[i] = make([]int, cL)
        }
        for i := 0; i < rL; i++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)
            sl = strings.Split(s, "")
            for j, v := range sl {
                temp, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
                mxL[i][j] = temp
            }
        }
        // Scanning small matrix
        fmt.Scanf("%d%d", &rS, &cS)
        mxS = make([][]int, rS)
        for i := range mxS {
            mxS[i] = make([]int, cS)
        }
        for i := 0; i < rS; i++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)
            sl = strings.Split(s, "")
            for j, v := range sl {
                temp, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
                mxS[i][j] = temp
            }
        }
        // Stop scanning input
        // Start searching for small matrix in large matrix
        found = true
        for iL := 0; iL <= rL-rS; iL++ {
            for jL := 0; jL <= cL-cS; jL++ {
                found = true
                if mxL[iL][jL] == mxS[0][0] {
                    for iS := 0; iS < rS; iS++ {
                        for jS := 1; jS < cS; jS++ {
                            if mxS[iS][jS] != mxL[iS+iL][jS+jL] {
                                found = false
                                break
                            }
                        }
                        if !found {
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    if found {
                        break
                    }
                } else {
                    found = false
                }
            }
            if found {
                fmt.Println("YES")
                break
            }
        }
        if !found {
            fmt.Println("NO")
        }
        // Stop searching for small matrix in large matrix
    }
}
```

I'm using a slice of slices of ints to store the input.

`mxL` is the large matrix and `mxS` is the small matrix.

`rL` and `cL` stand for row and column of the large matrix.

`rS` and `cS` stand for row and column of the small matrix.

Comment: `My code works but timeouts for the largest possible input`, so it doesn't work. Because the time limit is part of the problem: `My code works but it predicts tonight's weather tomorrow` is not a working code.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback, I've edited my text.

Comment: Maybe you need a different algorithm than just straightforward element by element comparison?

Comment: I'm sure there's a case study on variable naming for code clarity here somewhere. But that aside - a brute force approach is usually the least efficient way of tackling a problem - one obvious such optimisation is read the small matrix first, and then _as you are processing_ the large matrix, you can quickly discard any that don't contain the first row of the small matrix. (If you find that, then you will need to retain the next few lines)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My guess is that your break statements aren't canceling early enough. I have solved this in C++ with a brute force approach, using a subroutine ```find_brute_force_inner``` that makes canceling early more clear for me. I'd be surprised if Go was so much slower here. Have you found out more on this in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

Well I am gonna point out an idea to you and then you can try to implement it. So create a new 2d array as large as your large array. Call it sumArray. Now let each cell in this sumArray represent the sum where the current cell is the most bottom-left cell. Now what you do is check only the cells that has the same sum as your small array instead of checking every element in the array.

So if those are your inputs

```
1 1 1 1 1 1     
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1

1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
```

First sum your small array --> 8

Now let me show you how your sum array would look like

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1     -1 means that we can't sum at this point because
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1      the dimensions are just smaller than your small array
-1 -1  9  9  9  9      each other cell represent the sum of your original 
 9  9  9  9  9  9      matrix values.
 9  9  9  8  9  9
```

Now if you scan trough this array only you can see that you will reduce your search space from every possible position to only the position where your sum is equal. This doesn't guarantee that the array are in this position you still have to add a verification step but it reduce your search space.